# Cucumber and Rails 2.3.8: no such file to load -- spec/expectations (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, bdd

So... I just set up a clean rvm environment, hoping the issue would go away... alas, it did not.

Here is what I did

```
rvm use 1.8.7@cucumber-rails-2
gem install -v=2.3.8 rails
gem install cucumber -v0.10.3
rake gems:install
gem uninstall i18n (I can only use 0.4.2, 0.5 doesn't work with anything / causes conflicts)
gem install cucumber-rails -v0.3.2
script/generate cucumber
rake RAILS_ENV=cucumber gems:install
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ; gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -v 2.7 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
gem uninstall i18n (I can only use 0.4.2, 0.5 doesn't work with anything / causes conflicts)
rake gems:install RAILS_ENV=test
gem install hpricot    
gem uninstall crack (0.1.8 was causing a deprecation warning, so I uninstalled it (leaving me with 0.1.6))
```

then when I go rake cucumber:all
I get this:

```
Using the default profile...
no such file to load -- spec/expectations (MissingSourceFile)
```

Final gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (3.0.10, 2.3.8)
activemodel (3.0.10)
activerecord (2.3.14, 2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (3.0.10, 2.3.14, 2.3.8)
arel (2.0.10)
attr_encrypted (1.1.2)
awesome_print (0.4.0)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
capybara (1.0.1, 0.4.1.2)
celerity (0.9.0)
childprocess (0.2.2)
cobravsmongoose (0.0.2)
crack (0.1.6)
cucumber (0.10.3)
cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
culerity (0.2.15)
daemons (1.1.4)
database_cleaner (0.6.7)
delayed_job (2.0.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
eigenclass (1.1.1)
encryptor (1.1.3)
erubis (2.6.6)
factory_girl (2.0.5)
ffi (1.0.9)
friendly_id (3.0.6)
garb (0.7.6)
gherkin (2.4.16)
hpricot (0.8.4)
httparty (0.5.2)
i18n (0.4.2)
json (1.5.3)
json_pure (1.5.3)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.16)
mocha (0.9.12)
mysql (2.7)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.2)
pony (1.1)
rack (1.2.3, 1.1.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (2.3.8)
railties (3.0.10)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rspec (2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
searchlogic (2.5.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.5.0)
shoulda (2.11.3)
sms_fu (1.1.1)
ssl_requirement (0.1.0)
stringex (1.1.0)
term-ansicolor (1.0.6)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
webrat (0.7.3)
will_paginate (2.3.14)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

is spec/expectations suppossed to be a file I'm suppossed to have?

the last line in the call stack from my project is this:

```
require 'cucumber/rails/rspec'
```

stack trace:

```
Using the default profile...
no such file to load -- spec/expectations (MissingSourceFile)
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@cucumber-rails-2/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@cucumber-rails-2/gems/cucumber-rails-0.3.2/lib/cucumber/rails/rspec.rb:13
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@cucumber-rails-2/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/Users/me/Work/company/product/features/support/env.rb:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Rspec needs the ./spec folder to function, and from what I remember (it's late) ./spec/expectations is used by cucumber to define terms which you call in cucumber.

Whether that's the purpose or not, yes it is definitely looking for a file.